# How to send ACRA reports to multiple destinations?

Tags: android, acra, bugsense

I've this special case where in I need to send the crash reports from my app to both [BugSense](https://www.bugsense.com) and my own server. And [AdvancedUsage - ACRA/acra Wiki](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#reports-destination) says :

> "You can even send reports to multiple destinations."

But where and how exactly do I specify these?

The only solution I can think of is by implementing my own [`ReportSender`](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#implementing-your-own-sender) and making it post the data to both the servers. And I'm guessing that there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the solution I already talked about in the question (*by implementing our own version of `ReportSender`*), we can apparently also use the less obvious :

> [ACRA.getErrorReporter().addReportSender(ReportSender sender)](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/acra/ErrorReporter.java#L289)

This adds the `ReportSender` to `List<ReportSender> mReportSenders`, which is then iterated over while sending reports.