# ACRA crash report, send crash to multiple emails

Tags: java, android, crash-reports, acra

I want to send the `CrashReport` of my app to multiple recipients, is this possible **without** adding a `ErrorReporter`, just in the `@ReportCrashes`?
If not, what could be a possible solution?

Code:

```
import org.acra.ACRA;
import org.acra.ReportingInteractionMode;
import org.acra.annotation.ReportsCrashes;

@ReportsCrashes(
    mailTo = "******@gmail.com",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send ACRA reports to multiple destinations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901139/how-to-send-acra-reports-to-multiple-destinations)

Comment: I know it's not an answer to your question but there is a nice free library that does everything for you regarding crash reports, see crashlytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a own sender, like this:

```
public class YourOwnSender implements ReportSender {

  private String emails[];
  private Context context;

  public YourOwnSender(Context context, String[] additionalEmails){
    this.email = additionalEmails;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override
  public void send(CrashReportData report) throws ReportSenderException {
    StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();

    log.append("Package: " + report.get(ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME) + "\n");
    log.append("Version: " + report.get(ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE) + "\n");
    log.append("Android: " + report.get(ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION) + "\n");
    log.append("Manufacturer: " + android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER + "\n");
    log.append("Model: " + report.get(ReportField.PHONE_MODEL) + "\n");
    log.append("Date: " + now + "\n");
    log.append("\n");
    log.append(report.get(ReportField.STACK_TRACE));

    String body = log.toString();
    String subject = mContext.getPackageName() + " Crash Report";

    for(int i=0; i<emails.length; i++) {
      final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto", ACRAgetConfig().mailTo(), null));
    emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_BCC, emails);
    mContext.startActivity(emailIntent);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question suggests that you are looking to send to multiple email recipients. If that is the case then just comma separate them in the `mailTo` attribute. That is:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    mailTo = "******@gmail.com, someOne@another.address",
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text
)
```

You don't need to configure another `ReportSender` for that use case.